# Find duplicates in in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a talble like this..

```
BookId      BookName                                        BookProvider

1                   Angels and deamons                      Amazon
2                   Angels and deamons                      Amazon
3                   Angels and deamons                      Ebay
4                   Tuesdays                                Amazon                  
5                   SQL 101                                 Ebay
```

I would like to find all Book Names that are identical and exists in more than one unique BookProvider, how can I do that in a SQL query? In this example I would like to retrieve record 1 and 2 since tha book name is identical and it can be found on both amazon and ebay.

Comment: Do you want to include the BookProviders in the result?

Comment: can you put an example or more details it's not clear

Comment: You stilt want row 1 and 2? Not 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns all books with multiple rows for the same BookProvider:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY BookProvider, BookName) AS cnt 
   FROM @BookTable TT
 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
select  BookName from table
group by BookName
having count(distinct BookProvider)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the whole rows, including Bookid and BookProviders? Have a sub-query that returns the booknames that can be found in more than one store. Join with that result.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select BookName from tablename
      group by BookName
      having count(distinct BookProvider) > 1) t2
    on t1.BookName = t2.BookName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @BookProvider TABLE(
    Id int
    ,BookName VARCHAR(100)
    ,BookProvider VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @BookProvider
VALUES(1, 'Angels and Demons', 'Amazon')
INSERT INTO @BookProvider
VALUES(2, 'Angels and Demons', 'Ebay')
INSERT INTO @BookProvider
VALUES(3, 'Tuesdays', 'Amazon')
INSERT INTO @BookProvider
VALUES(4, 'SQL 101', 'Ebay')

SELECT BookName, COUNT(DISTINCT BookProvider) as Count FROM @BookProvider 
GROUP BY BookName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BookProvider) > 1
```

Results:

```
+-------------------+-------+
|     BookName      | Count |
+-------------------+-------+
| Angels and Demons |     2 |
+-------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
select count(bookname),bookname from tablename group by bookname having count(bookname)>1
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a mistake in my initial question, I need it to be based on unique Bookproviders too. I updated the initial post..

Answer (score 0):

You can even use a CTE with a partion as well if you want to view all the books and their counts:

```
DECLARE @BookTable TABLE
(
    BookId int,
    BookName varchar(100),
    BookProvider varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @BookTable
(
    BookId,
    BookName,
    BookProvider
)
VALUES
(1, 'Angel and Demons', 'Amazon'),
(2, 'Angel and Demons', 'EBay'),
(3, 'Tuesdays','Amazon'),
(4, 'SQL 101', 'Amazon');

WITH BookCte 
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TT.BookName ORDER BY TT.BookName) as RowNumber FROM @BookTable TT
)

SELECT * FROM BookCte BC
```